# HTTP 404 - File not found Internet Explorer V6

Tags: php, windows, internet-explorer, http-status-code-404

I have ang 404 code that will redirect to the site if the page is not found. It working properly in firefox. However, when I use the Internet Explorer v6. the site will get and error mesaage: "HTTP 404 - File not found Internet Explore". How can I fix this? any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: So, do we need to take our telepathy sphere and read the code directly from your mind?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to use a longer 404 page. That's no joke. If the 404 page is less than 512b if I remember correctly, IE will step in and show its own error message.

Adding in some comments will do.

Reference: http://www.reddit.com/r/web_design/comments/ee4zc/so_i_looked_at_plesks_404_page/

Just for completeness:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>404 Not Found</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Not Found</H1>
The requested document was not found on this server.
<P>
<HR>
<ADDRESS>
Web Server at example.com
</ADDRESS>
</BODY>
</HTML>

<!--
   - Unfortunately, Microsoft has added a clever new
   - "feature" to Internet Explorer. If the text of
   - an error's message is "too small", specifically
   - less than 512 bytes, Internet Explorer returns
   - its own error message. You can turn that off,
   - but it's pretty tricky to find switch called
   - "smart error messages". That means, of course,
   - that short error messages are censored by default.
   - IIS always returns error messages that are long
   - enough to make Internet Explorer happy. The
   - workaround is pretty simple: pad the error
   - message with a big comment like this to push it
   - over the five hundred and twelve bytes minimum.
   - Of course, that's exactly what you're reading
   - right now.
   -->
```

Comment: Oh wow, haven't seen this one in a while, even used that same comment in my own code along the lines.

Comment: MYYN, I tried it but it doesnt work. it doesnt redirect at all

Comment: i think i fixed it. i just recode my 404.php to this: header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;

Comment: With IE9, the exact value was less than 512 bytes (I ran into this same issue yesterday, except for a 500 error). I used 512 anyway in case IE8 did.