# USing PHP header() function to send 404 error in IE

Tags: php, header, http-headers, http-status-code-404, httpresponse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTTP 404 - File not found Internet Explorer V6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456738/http-404-file-not-found-internet-explorer-v6)

I was testing if it's possible to send a 404 error with php header function:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
echo "test";
die();
```

I sniffed the request and in both firefox and IE the HTTP status code is 404, but the difference is that Firefox show the echo "test", but IE doesn't, it opens the IE custom 404 page. I also tried sending the echo before the header(), and still FF opens fine, IE shows IE's 404.

Is there a way to send a custom 404 error page with header() function in IE like it's possible in Firefox?

Comment: I use `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` apache clause and then have a custom `404.php` file without sending a `header()`

Comment: What version of IE?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php "There is a bug in Microsoft Internet Explorer 4.01 that prevents this from working. There is no workaround. There is also a bug in Microsoft Internet Explorer 5.5 that interferes with this, which can be resolved by upgrading to Service Pack 2 or later."

Comment: @sdolgy: If OP is still on IE 4/5, then OP should be slapped around with a cluebat for a few years. If IE6 is pathetically bad, then 4/5 are beyond moronically stupid.

Comment: @Marc B: I don't really use IE but I did the testing on IE 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to output more data due to IE feature. Try to ouput more than 600 characters

Comment: i'd vote up if you could post some reference material about how you arrived at this conclusion?  why 600 characters?  what versions of IE does this affect? .... also, this doesn't seem like a "feature"

Comment: Few seconds of googling http://www.reddit.com/r/web_design/comments/ee4zc/so_i_looked_at_plesks_404_page/ `- Unfortunately, Microsoft has added a clever new
   - "feature" to Internet Explorer. If the text of
   - an error's message is "too small", specifically
   - less than 512 bytes, Internet Explorer returns
   - its own error message. `